# Unity How to access property on ResolvedParameter<T> and inject into RegisterType

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to register a type that takes 2 strings as a parameter in it's constructor. The strings are properties off of two other registered types. I have tried the following, but the parameters are empty when IDatabaseManagement is injected even though the other injection types resolve and have values for the properties:

```
container.RegisterType<IConnectionInfo, ConnectionInfo>()
          .RegisterType<IUserInfo, UserInfo>()
          .RegisterType<IDatabaseManagement, DatabaseManagement>(new InjectionConstructor(
            container.Resolve<IConnectionInfo>().Connection
            ,
            container.Resolve<IUserInfo>().CurrentUser.UserEmployeeNumber
            ));
```

I have also tried casting a ResolvedParameter, but that blows up on the casting:

```
container.RegisterType<IConnectionInfo, ConnectionInfo>()
          .RegisterType<IUserInfo, UserInfo>()
          .RegisterType<IDatabaseManagement, DatabaseManagement>(new InjectionConstructor(
            ((IConnectionInfo)(new ResolvedParameter<IConnectionInfo>())).Connection
            ,
            ((IUserInfo)(new ResolvedParameter<IUserInfo>())).CurrentUser.UserEmployeeNumber
            ));
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you want a factory for producing your DatabaseManagement instances, unless your application only has a single instance which is for the current user at startup?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest answer would be to change your `DatabaseManagement` constructor to take in an `IConnectionInfo` and an `IUserInfo` instead of two strings.

If that is not acceptable, you can use an `InjectionFactory` instead.

```
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseManagement, DatabaseManagement>(
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        var connectionInfo = c.Resolve<IConnectionInfo>();
        var userInfo = c.Resolve<IUserInfo>();

        return new DatabaseManagement(
            connectionInfo.Connection,
            userInfo.CurrentUser.UserEmployeeNumber);
    }));
```

The reason it is failing in your first example is becuase it is resolving an instance of `IConnectionInfo` and `IUserInfo` immediately upon executing the RegisterType call and using those single instances for all resolves of `IDatabaseManagement`.  An `InjectionFactory` is executed every time Resolve is called.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

I have my IDataContext for MSSQL and another for MySQL.

This example uses named type resolution. Take note of "db" named resolving. You must pass New InjectionConstructor to each type that requires specific named resolution.

```
            container.RegisterType(Of IDataContextAsync, dbEntities)("db", New InjectionConstructor())
            container.RegisterType(Of IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork)("UnitOfWork", New InjectionConstructor(New ResolvedParameter(Of IDataContextAsync)("db")))

            'Exceptions example
            container.RegisterType(Of IRepositoryAsync(Of Exception), Repository(Of Exception))("iExceptionRepository",
                                                                                                         New InjectionConstructor(New ResolvedParameter(Of IDataContextAsync)("db"),
                                                                                                                                  New ResolvedParameter(Of IUnitOfWorkAsync)("UnitOfWork")))
```

'sql container

```
    container.RegisterType(Of IDataContextAsync, DataMart)(New HierarchicalLifetimeManager)
            container.RegisterType(Of IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork)(New HierarchicalLifetimeManager)

            'brands
            container.RegisterType(Of IRepositoryAsync(Of Brand), Repository(Of Brand))
```